# Query a list in AngularFire2 for available items with non-null values & optional "key" parameter

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm doing a query in AgularFire2 where I look for items that has some particular property (value is not important, just that particular item has some value is enough) by using empty string for `startAt`, it works as expected.

Since Beta 8 can use "optional key value" in queries (`startAt`, `endAt` and `equalTo`) , I wanted to get only certain elements, starting from a given `key`.

Here is an example:

```
[
  {"$key": "a", "email":"alice@gmail.com","name":"Alice"},
  {"$key": "b", "email":"bob@gmail.com","name":"Bob"},
  {"$key": "m", "name":"Malory"}
]
```

this query doesn't return only "Bob", but both Bob & Alice:

```
    query: {
      startAt: { value: '', key: 'b'},
      orderByChild: 'email'
    }
```

Here is a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/1iaIUp?p=preview).

**UPDATE:** (example to clarify what I want to achieve)

Assume we have a list `dealers` in our db, and each dealer has one or more sorts of `vehicles` in their inventory (trucks, busses, cars..etc): `dealers/{dealerUid}/inventory`

I've first tried it with deep path (like: `orderByChild: 'inventory/cars'`) and see the unexpected behavior, but same happens in first level queries. (assume I only want to get dealers that have cars in their inventory, but starting from some uid(`{dealerUid}`), not all dealers having cars in inventory.

Either I am doing something wrong or there is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional key is used to differentiate between multiple matches of the specified value. From the [SDK documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#startAt):

> The optional key argument can be used to further limit the range of the query. If it is specified, then children that have exactly the specified value must also have a key name greater than or equal to the specified key.

You have no matches for the value you have specified and all of the values in the database sort *after* the value you have specified, so all children are returned.

What you are seeing is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Actually, the last returned child doesn't have an `email`. It's possible that that child's inclusion is a bug. I would have thought a `null` should sort before an empty string.

Comment: no, I've copied that child in this post just to show all available elements. You are right, this is expected. My mistake.

Comment: Further thinking, while this is valid behavior for Firebase SDK, maybe empty string should be considered special case and if `startAt` / `endAt` has both empty string as value and a key given, then it should behave returning values only from that key further and not all available values. You think it makes sense I open a feature request?

Comment: If you want that behaviour, seeing as though you know the key, why not just use `startAt` with that key and that key's child value?

Comment: What I want is to fetch only elements that have some particular property (value /object contained in that property is not important), but amongst those elements, I'd like to get only ones starting from particular `key` value.

Comment: Updated my post with more elaborate example

Comment: It's just not going to work like that. All querying in Firebase is either based on matching a specific value or matching values within a range. And the optional key is used only when there are multiple matches for a single value. At the core of it, you appear to be asking for a `notEqualTo` method - as you want to use `notEqualTo(null, someKey)` to match any existing property - but there isn't one.